# Issue creating a car for a user in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im very new tor ails and still learning. My project that I am working on is set up for a user to have many cars and cars belong to a user.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    has_secure_password 
    has_many :cars

end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My flow is set up to where after a user signs in they can create their vehicle. However I am having trouble creating the car so that it will attach to the user and I am getting an error each time I try different methods.

```
 def create
        @car = Car.new(car_params)
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @car.save
        redirect_to user_path
    end


 private
    def car_params
        params.require(:car).permit(:user_id, :make, :model, :color)
    end
```

my schema seems to be set up correctly

```
create_table "cars", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "make"
    t.string "model"
    t.string "color"
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_cars_on_user_id"
  end
```

But again, I am clearly doing something wrong and I am having trouble finding my answers online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have a login, you probably have a `current_user` set up. The logged one. Inside your create method on your controller you can set the car information using the logged in user like:

```
def create
  @car = Car.new(car_params)
  @car.user_id = current_user.id
  @car.save
  redirect_to user_path
end
```

You can also remove the `:user_id` from the `car_params` if you have the information about the logged user.

If you don't have the `current_user` or whatever method to get the logged in user created, you will need to select the user inside the form via a HTML select or something like that, then you can keep the `:user_id` inside `car_params` and just remove the line about setting the user_id on @car to save.

Comment: Thanks I did have a current_user method set up in my applications controller. 
I ended up doing this: 

```
def create
        @user = current_user
        @car = @user.cars.create(car_params)
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
    end
```
and it worked for me. But I like your method. Its cleaner

Comment: No problem, be sure to upvote and accept to help other people.